# Transition probabilities in multi dimensional birth-death process

Tags: probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, markov-process, uniform-distribution

I've got an urn problem that I believe can be nicely modeled as a birth-death process (I'm very new to markov chains, so maybe this is simply the wrong approach). Suppose we have $k$ urns each of which can hold a finite number of $n$ distinct balls labelled $1, \cdots, n$. The number of urns can increases without bound and there are no empty urns allowed, however, the state where there are no urns ($k = 0$) is allowed.

1. With some probability $q_k$ choose an urn uniformly at random

   1.1 With probability $1/2$ add a ball whose label is not already in the urn, otherwise remove a ball.

   - if the urn is full, do nothing.
   - if we remove the last ball from the urn, remove the urn all together and $k \rightarrow k-1$.
2. With probability $1-q_k$, add a new urn with a single ball chosen uniformly at random. ($k \rightarrow k+1$)

If $K$ is a random variable representing the number of existing urns and $U_i$ a random variable representing the number of balls currently in urn $i$ (number of balls in each urn is assumed to be independent), the goal is for

$$P\left(K = k\right) = \frac{1}{k!}e^{-1}$$ and

$$
P(U) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k P(U_i = n_i) = \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k{n \choose n_i}} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k\frac{n_i!\left(n-n_i\right)!}{n!}
$$

where $1\leq n_i\leq n$ is the number of balls in urn $i$.

i.e. the number of balls in the urns should be uniformly distributed.

My goal is to get an expression for $q_k$.

I have a solution for the case where urns can only hold one ball:

This what I believe the markov chain looks like for this case, where each number in the circle represents the number of urns.
[image]

Let $\alpha_i = \pi_{i,i+1}$ and $\beta_i = \pi_{i,i-1}$, where p_i = P(K=i)

Detailed balance requires that:
$p_i\alpha_i = p_{i+1}\beta_{i+1}$ for $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $p_j = \sum_i p_i\pi_{ij}$

When $i = 0$
$$
p_0 = \beta_1p_1 +(1-\alpha_0)p_0 
$$

and in general

$$
p_i = \alpha_{i-1}p_{i-1} + \beta_{i+1}p_{i+1} + (1-\alpha_i-\beta_i)p_i \tag{1}
$$

the base case is such that
$$
\alpha_0p_0 = \beta_1p_1
$$
assuming $\alpha_{i-1}p_{i-1} = \beta_ip_i$ then we can substitute this into Equation (1) and get

$$
\alpha_i p_i = \beta_{i+1}p_{i+1}
$$

meaning the detailed balance can be satisfied pairwise

now suppose $\alpha_i = \alpha$ and $\beta_{i+1} = (i+1)\beta$ for all $i$, then

$$
p_1 = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}p_0
$$
and we can do induction on $i$ and get

$$
p_i = \frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^i}{i!}p_0
$$

normalizing this, implies $p_0 = \exp{\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)}$ and letting $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = 1$

$$
p_i = \frac{1}{i!}e^{-1}
$$

which is the distribution I want, assuming each urn can only hold $1$ ball and I can set $q_i = \alpha/(i+1)$ for any $\alpha < 1/2$.

I'm having difficulty, however, following the line of thinking above to generalize this to urns that can hold more than $1$ ball.

I have a solution where I made a rather ad-hoc order $1/n$ approximation and get that $q_i = \frac{1}{2n(i+1)}$ where $i$ is the current number of urns and $n$ is the maximum number of balls an urn can hold (I verfied with some simulations that this does indeed sample from the distributions that I am looking for but I will spare the derivation to avoid making this post longer than it already is). But I feel like I there should be a better way than this approximation I made to solve this problem, something similar to what I did for the $n =1$ case. Is there a way to solve this problem following such a line of thinking?

Comment: This question needs some clarifiying, since you are dealing with markov-chains there is no general $K$, just $K_t$ the number of urns at time $t$. Also $P(U_{(t)})$ needs an actual event which explains, what $n$ and $n_i$ in the remaining formula mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think the derivation in the 1D case doesn't match with the description of the problem given as it says that $q_i$ decreases with $i$ which means you are likely to keep on adding urns which doesn't make sense with steady state probabilities decreasing with $i$. Assuming you have a solution for the 1D case for the given description, the following **might** work

One possibility is to change your state space to also include n. Specifically, if you take the state space to be $\mathcal{S} = \mathbb{N}^n$ where the markov chain being in a state $\vec{x} = (x_1 , \ldots , x_n )$ represents that currently you have $x_i$ urns with $i$ balls (I am guessing this is the multi in the multi-dimensional asked in the title). Now you can define the transitions in a more refined way.

Let $S(\vec{x})$ denote the sum of all the components of $\vec{x}$. Then from what I understand in the question, we require that the chain be irreducible and the steady state probabilities satisfy
$$\Sigma_{\{\vec{x} | S(\vec{x})= k\}} \pi_{\vec{x}} = \frac{1}{k!} e^{-1} = \pi_k $$

From state $\vec{x}$ and denoting $S(\vec{x})$ by $k$, with probability $1-q_k$ we add a new urn $\textit{i.e}$
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \xrightarrow{1-q_k} (x_1+1, \ldots, x_n)$$

Next in the remaining probability $q_k$ we choose an urn uniformly at random and either add or remove a ball at random. This implies that
$$ \vec{x} \longrightarrow \begin{cases} (x_1-1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) & \textrm{w.p } (x_1/2k).q_k \\
 (x_1-1, x_2+1, \ldots, x_n) & \textrm{w.p } (x_1/2k).q_k \\
(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{i-1}+1,x_{i}-1, \ldots, x_n) & \textrm{w.p } (x_i/2k).q_k \; \forall \, 2\leqslant i \leqslant n \\
(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{i}-1,x_{i+1}+1, \ldots, x_n) & \textrm{w.p } (x_i/2k).q_k \; \forall \, 2\leqslant i < n \\
\vec{x} & \textrm{w.p } (x_n/2k).q_k
\end{cases} $$

It should be clear that the chain defined this way is irreducible and aperiodic over $\mathcal{S}$. Now defining $$\pi_{\vec{x}} = \frac{\binom{k}{x_1, \ldots, x_n}}{n^k} \pi_k$$ I think will satisfy the detailed balance equations